# Using CKEditor with Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, ckeditor

How can I use CKEditor with play framework?

I'm using:

```
@helper.textarea(ProfileForm("aboutme"), '_label -> "About Me")</br>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'aboutme', {height: 164} );
            </script>
```

The form will load the textarea data when the editor script is removed, but when it is added the data from the textarea does not reach my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you would like to render a prefilled textarea.

To do this you should prefill your form in your controller with something like this:

```
public static Result textArea() {
    Form<ProfileForm> profileForm = form(ProfileForm.class);
    ProfileForm profileForm_ = new ProfileForm();
    profileForm_.aboutMe = "hello";
    profileForm = profileForm.fill(profileForm_);
    return ok(views.html.textarea.render(profileForm));
}
```

This will render your text area with the content "hello".

Your form in your view should looks like something like this:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.textAreaSubmit()) {
    @helper.textarea(
        profileForm("aboutMe"),
        '_label -> "About me : ",
        'class -> "editable"
    )
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit"/>
}
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'aboutMe', {height: 164} );
</script>
```

Don't forget to add the profileForm object as a parameter in the header of your view:

```
@(profileForm: Form[beans.ProfileForm])
```